# How to correct the error concerning the order \multicolumn?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I have a LaTeX code that works fine in my first template but when I copy it to my new template, it doesn't work and I really don't know why I get this error:

> Misplaced \noalign.  You have used a \hline command in the wrong
> place, probably outside a table. If the \hline command is written
> inside a table, try including \ before it.

This is the link to my file in Overleaf: `https://www.overleaf.com/1445775647ghxgtdjxxdwx`

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[USenglish]{article}  
% for 2-column layout use \documentclass[USenglish,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             %(only for the pdftex engine)
%\RequirePackage[no-math]{fontspec}[2017/03/31]%(only for the luatex or the xetex engine)
\usepackage[big,online]{dgruyter}   %values: small,big | online,print,work
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[numbers,square,sort&compress]{natbib}


% New theorem-like environments will be introduced by using the commands \theoremstyle and \newtheorem.
% Please note that the environments proof and definition are already defined within dgryuter.sty.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\begin{document}

    
%%%--------------------------------------------%%%
    \articletype{Research Article}
    \received{Month DD, YYYY}
    \revised{Month  DD, YYYY}
  \accepted{Month   DD, YYYY}
  \journalname{De~Gruyter~Journal}
  \journalyear{YYYY}
  \journalvolume{XX}
  \journalissue{X}
  \startpage{1}
  \aop
  \DOI{10.1515/sample-YYYY-XXXX}
%%%--------------------------------------------%%%

\title{Insert your title here}
\runningtitle{Short title}
%\subtitle{Insert subtitle if needed}

\author*[1]{First Author}
%\ use * to mark the author as the corresponding author
\author[2]{Second Author}
\author[2]{Third Author} 
\runningauthor{F.~Author et al.}
\affil[1]{\protect\raggedright 
Institution, Department, City, Country of first author, e-mail: author\_one@xx.yz}
\affil[2]{\protect\raggedright 
Institution, Department, City, Country of second author and third author, e-mail: author\_two@xx.yz, author\_three@xx.yz}
    
%\communicated{...}
%\dedication{...}
    
\abstract{}

\keywords{Please insert your keywords here, separated by commas.}
    
        
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    
    \hline
       \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Gaussian } & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{IMQ}\\ \hline
          Level & Cond($\mathbf{A}$) & Max EV & Min EV & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} Cholesky\\  Y/N? \end{tabular}}  & Cond($\mathbf{A}$) & Max EV & Min EV &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} Cholesky\\  Y/N? \end{tabular}} \\ \hline
        1 & 3.55E+00 & -3.3E+00 & -1.2E+01 & Y & 1.76E+00 & -5.4E+00 & -9.6E+00 & Y \\ \hline
        2 & 7.13E+00 & -6.7E+00 & -4.8E+01 & Y & 2.41E+00 & -3.2E+01 & -7.7E+01 & Y \\ \hline
        3 & 1.78E+01 & -1.1E+01 & -1.9E+02 & Y & 3.59E+00 & -1.7E+02 & -6.2E+02 & Y \\ \hline
        4 & 5.09E+01 & -1.5E+01 & -7.7E+02 & Y & 5.26E+00 & -9.5E+02 & -5.0E+03 & Y \\ \hline
        5 & 1.36E+02 & -2.3E+01 & -3.1E+03 & Y & 6.84E+00 & -5.9E+03 & -4.0E+04 & Y \\ \hline
        6 & 2.69E+02 & -4.6E+01 & -1.2E+04 & Y & 7.81E+00 & -4.1E+04 & -3.2E+05 & Y \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{The condition number of the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ and the minimum/maximum eigenvalue of the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ using  Gaussian RBF and IMQ RBF with $C=1$.}
    \label{Tab: Cond_A_C1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

How can I fix this error please?

Comment: If I complete your code with `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`, I don't get an error.

Comment: I just edit the code in my question, I complete it, It doesn't work!!

Comment: It works for me.  Is it possibly a different table that's causing you problems?  The error message should indicate a line number.  Have you copy and pasted this code from a document that contains nothing else?

Comment: yeh!! it contains only this table, please see the code, I edit it again, I added the whole code.

Comment: `dgruyter` is not a standard package, I have managed to locate it but you should really include links to files we do not have access to, I have found your template on Overleaf here https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/manuscript-template-for-walter-de-gruyter-books-and-journals/gjpwcwpwhgmb

Comment: @walidfssm: We cannot replicate your current issue with the code you provided. Can you update your code to reproduce the problem? If nothing else, remove all auxiliary files from your working folder and try compiling again; the problem might be related to a issue with one of those files.

Comment: @JamesT  Thanks for the comment, I added the link to my file in Overleaf    https://www.overleaf.com/1445775647ghxgtdjxxdwx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user guide of the `dgruyter` package states unequivocally that vertical rules should *not* be used in tables. The user guide states, moreover, that the `booktabs` package is loaded automatically by the `dgruyter` package, meaning that you should use commands such as `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\bottomrule` and `\cmidrule` instead of `\hline` and `\cline`.

With this in mind, the following solution -- which also makes use of the capabilities of the `siunitx` package to typeset numbers in scientific format -- should be of interest to you.

[image]

```
\documentclass[english]{article}  
% for 2-column layout use \documentclass[USenglish,twocolumn]{article}

%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default
%\RequirePackage[no-math]{fontspec}[2017/03/31]%(only for the luatex or the xetex engine)
\usepackage[big,online]{dgruyter}   %values: small,big | online,print,work
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[numbers,square,sort&compress]{natbib}


%%%%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
%\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{hhline}
%\usepackage{empheq}
%\usepackage{blindtext}
%%%%%\usepackage{multicol} % not needed
%\usepackage{tabularray}

% new:
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}

    
%%%--------------------------------------------%%%
    \articletype{Research Article}
    \received{Month DD, YYYY}
    \revised{Month  DD, YYYY}
  \accepted{Month   DD, YYYY}
  \journalname{De~Gruyter~Journal}
  \journalyear{YYYY}
  \journalvolume{XX}
  \journalissue{X}
  \startpage{1}
  \aop
  \DOI{10.1515/sample-YYYY-XXXX}
%%%--------------------------------------------%%%

\title{Insert your title here}
\runningtitle{Short title}
%\subtitle{Insert subtitle if needed}

\author*[1]{First Author}
%\ use * to mark the author as the corresponding author
\author[2]{Second Author}
\author[2]{Third Author} 
\runningauthor{F.~Author et al.}
\affil[1]{\protect\raggedright 
Institution, Department, City, Country of first author, e-mail: author\_one@xx.yz}
\affil[2]{\protect\raggedright 
Institution, Department, City, Country of second author and third author, e-mail: author\_two@xx.yz, author\_three@xx.yz}
    
%\communicated{...}
%\dedication{...}
    
\abstract{}

\keywords{Please insert your keywords here, separated by commas.}
    
 
\begin{table}[h]
\sisetup{tight-spacing,print-zero-exponent}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out intercol. whitespace

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
   l 
   S[table-format= 1.2e1] *{2}{S[table-format=-1.1e1]} c 
   S[table-format= 1.2e1] *{2}{S[table-format=-1.1e1]} c }
    
    %\toprule % is automatic
    Level & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Gaussian} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{IMQ} \\ 
    \cmidrule{2-5} \cmidrule{6-9}
    & {Cond($\mathbf{A}$)} & {Max EV} & {Min EV} & Cholesky?  & 
      {Cond($\mathbf{A}$)} & {Max EV} & {Min EV} & Cholesky? 
    \\ 
    \midrule
        1 & 3.55E+00 & -3.3E+00 & -1.2E+01 & Y &   1.76E+00 & -5.4E+00 & -9.6E+00 & Y \\
        2 & 7.13E+00 & -6.7E+00 & -4.8E+01 & Y &   2.41E+00 & -3.2E+01 & -7.7E+01 & Y \\
        3 & 1.78E+01 & -1.1E+01 & -1.9E+02 & Y &   3.59E+00 & -1.7E+02 & -6.2E+02 & Y \\
        4 & 5.09E+01 & -1.5E+01 & -7.7E+02 & Y &   5.26E+00 & -9.5E+02 & -5.0E+03 & Y \\ 
        5 & 1.36E+02 & -2.3E+01 & -3.1E+03 & Y &   6.84E+00 & -5.9E+03 & -4.0E+04 & Y \\ 
        6 & 2.69E+02 & -4.6E+01 & -1.2E+04 & Y &   7.81E+00 & -4.1E+04 & -3.2E+05 & Y \\ 
    %\bottomrule % is automatic
    \end{tabular*}
    \caption{The condition number of the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ and the minimum\slash maximum eigenvalue of the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ using  Gaussian RBF and IMQ RBF with $C=1$.}
    \label{Tab: Cond_A_C1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please find attached the link to my file in Overleaf, it doesn't work for me at all.      https://www.overleaf.com/1445775647ghxgtdjxxdwx

Comment: @walidfssm -- *Why* do you still have `tabular` environments in the header cells? It didn't work for you before, and I was careful to remove them from the code I posted above. What makes you think that something that clearly didn't work before will all of a sudden start to work after all? And why do you keep using vertical rules when the user guide of the `dgruyter` package instructs users not to do so?